# Remove items from different Lists with same Menu

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, contextmenu

I have two listviews in an activity and i want to use a ContextMenu to remove itens from one of them. I want to use the same Context Menu, is that possible? I was looking here but all answers point to two differents Context Menus. Thanks!!!

Here is my code:

```
    //Register both ListViews
    Listview1= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.PedlstItens) ;
    Listview1.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    registerForContextMenu(Listview1);

    Listview2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.PedlstCartao) ;
    Listview2.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    registerForContextMenu(Listview2);
```

After that, inflate menu:

```
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_remove, menu);
}
```

Then the ContextMenu Behavior... i don't know how to point to the right Listview to remove the item:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        ***//THIS IS WHERE I DONT KNOW WHAT TO DO***
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.remove_item:
            Listview1.remove(info.position);
            Listview1array.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

In "onCreateContextMenu" i stored the Id of my list in the variable ListToRemove:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        ListToRemove = v.getId(); //Here i store in which listview my ContextMenu was created
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_remove, menu);
    }
```

Then, in the "onContextItemSelected", i made a switch to control the behavior. ***Note: My ContextMenu has only 1 item, so i removed the "getItemId()" from original code.

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    boolean retorno = false;

    switch (ListToRemove ) { 
    case R.id.ListView1:
        {
             ListView1.remove(info.position);
         ListView1Array.notifyDataSetChanged();
         retorno = true;
             break;
        }
    case R.id.ListView2:
        {
             ListView2.remove(info.position);
             ListView2Array.notifyDataSetChanged();
             retorno = true;
             break;
        }
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

Works great!!!